# How to find the neighbours of a node in Lemon

Tags: c++, graph, lemon-graph-library

In the Lemon C++ Graph Library, given a node in an undirected graph say, how does one find other nodes that are edge connected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll have a go at this even though I'm rusty with C++ and haven't used Lemon before:

```
for (ListDigraph::OutArcIt arcIt(graph, node); arcIt != INVALID; ++arcIt) {

    Arc arc(*arcIt); // Lemon iterators are supposed to be convertible to items
                     // without operator*, so arc(a) might work too.

    Node oppositeNode( g.oppositeNode(node, arc) );

    // Do something with the opposite node.
    ...
}
```

I used this:
[LEMON -- an Open Source C++ Graph Template Library](http://people.inf.elte.hu/kpeter/download/lemon_presentation_wgt_2010.pdf)

... and this:
[LEMON: Graph Class Reference](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/1.1.1/a00127.html)

... and I've done a reasonable amount of work with graph theory over the years.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it was actually IncEdgeIt that I was looking for which is the equivalent for undirected graphs, but you put me on the right path and stopped some serious hair-pulling-out